# TVFs and user-defined table types

Tags: user-defined-functions, user-defined-types

In SQL Server 2005 I have

```
create type MyTableType as table 
 ( MyField1 int,
 MyField2 varchar(80)

  )
```

Apparently I can do this:

```
create function MyFunc_A(...)
returns table( MyField1 int, MyField2 varchar(80), ... )
as begin
```

but not this:

```
create function MyFunc_A(...)
returns @result MyTableType
as begin
```

Problem is, I need dozens of MyFunc's which have to be reusable. And  MyTableType is almost certainly going to change. I don't want to go to each udf and make the changes.

Am I missing something in my second example?

Answer (score 0):

you may do

```
create funciton foo (...)
returns table
as
return
select
...
```

but in this case your function can not contain any additional logic. only SELECT query